# How to find out who called a method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Example: When my method -fooBar gets called, I want it to log in the console which other method of which other class called it.

Right now, I only know how to log the method name of fooBar itself and it's class, with this:

```
_cmd

[self class]
```

Is this possible to figure out?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In fully optimized code, there is no 100% surefire way to determine the caller to a certain method.   The compiler may employ a tail call optimization whereas the compiler effectively re-uses the caller's stack frame for the callee.

To see an example of this, set a breakpoint on any given method using gdb and look at the backtrace.  Note that you don't see objc_msgSend() before every method call.  That is because objc_msgSend() does a tail call to each method's implementation.

While you could compile your application non-optimized, you would need non-optimized versions of all of the system libraries to avoid just this one problem.

And this is just but one problem;  in effect, you are asking "how do I re-invent CrashTracer or gdb?".   A very hard problem upon which careers are made.   Unless you want "debugging tools" to be your career, I would recommend against going down this road.

What question are you really trying to answer?

Comment: @alexgray How is it an anti-answer?   The answer is exactly precise in scope and scale of the problem and, given the acceptance and final question, hopefully led the OP down a path to success.

Answer (score 7):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9603733/939050):

```
NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];

NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
[array removeObject:@""];

NSLog(@"Class caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Method caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:4]);
```

Credits to the original author, [intropedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526712/intropedro).

Comment: That won't work in fully optimized code as tail-call optimizations make frames disappear entirely from the stack.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible in the general case without actually walking the stack. There's not even a guarantee that another object send the message that called the method. For example, it could be called from a block in a signal handler.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLog(@"Show stack trace: %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [backtrace(3)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

User the below method

Pass index for which you want to display method and pass -1 if you want to display full stack of method

```
+(void) methodAtIndex:(int)index{
    void* callstack[128];
    int frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
    char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);

    if (index == -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (index < frames) {
            printf("%s\n", strs[index]);
        }
    }
    free(strs);

}
```

Comment: I'm getting `error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): no variable named '_cmd' found in this frame`

Answer (score 1):

This information can be obtained using [`DTrace`](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/26/objective-c-printing-class-name-from-dtrace/).

Answer (score 1):

Make a macro that adds the `__FUNCTION__` to the function name to the function call.  This macro will then call your function with an extra parameter of a char* to the target function.

Comment: That assumes that you have control over the caller and can change the ABI between caller and callee by changing the argumentation, which is rarely the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to catch who, how and when changes window's size and did some handwork:

```
- (void)logWindowWidth:(NSString *)whoCalls {
   NSLog(@"%@", whoCalls);
   NSLog(@"self.window.size.width %f", self.window.size.width);
}

-(void)someMethod {
  [self logWindowWidth:@"someMethod - before"];
  ...
  [self logWindowWidth:@"someMethod - after"];
}

-(void)anotherMethod {
  [self logWindowWidth:@"anotherMethod - before"];
  ...
  [self logWindowWidth:@"anotherMethod - after"];
}
```