# How can I get information about who called a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to get some information on who called a particular method.  Namely, if possible, getting the line number and file name of the method that made the call.  Akin to **FILE** and **LINE**, except one level down in the stack.  This is possible in high-level languages, but any way to do it in Objective-C?

```
- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"I was called by file %@, line #%i", callingFile, callingLine);
}
```

Comment: This is an exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. You have to tell the user to pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` themselves.

```
#define myMethod myMethodWithFile:__FILE__ line:__LINE__
...
-(void)myMethodWithFile:(const char*)file line:(int)line {
  NSLog(@"I was called by file %s, line #%d", file, line);
}
...
[obj myMethod];
```