# Finding caller method from called

Tags: objective-c, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out who called a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method)

I have multiple classes and multiple methods calling a method on a singleton class. I want to know which method is calling, without passing a flag. I am already passing self to child I know which class is calling using `[classObj class];` But I could not figure out how to identify which method is calling it.

Comment: As a side note, this feels like a bad pattern and you should reanalyze why you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I definitely recommend against doing this (Pass a flag as you suggest yourself), here's how you would see one level up in your call stack:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1]);
```