# Objective C: Method have knowledge of context within which it was called?

Tags: objective-c, nslog, objective-c-runtime

I'd like to have a reusable logging method or function that spits out the name of the method it's called from. Example:

```
    - (void)exampleMethod {
        CustomLog(); //Outputs "exampleMethod"
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451342/objective-c-find-caller-of-method ?

Comment: The question is a duplicate (didn't see that and yes I did search), but the answer provided to that question was not useful anyway. Two useful answers have been provided to this question below. Thanks for finding the dupe though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions don't know about their calling environment (at least not in a useful way). The only way is to use a macro instead. Inside the macro, you have access to the `self` and `_cmd` arguments that hold the receiver and current selector, as well as the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro that contains the human-readable name of the method as a C string.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to print out the method name and line number and conditionally disable NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks) for the inspiration for this answer and other useful NSLog tips. Here is what I desired:

```
//place in PCH file
#define ILog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

//use in any file in your project
ILog(@"test");// outputs -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] [Line 38] test
```