# How to get caller if the function has no -sender parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For example, there are functions named `-(void)Foo`, and `-(void)Foo:(id)sender`.

The `-(void)Foo:(id)sender` can get the caller from parameter, and my question is, how to get caller from `-(void)Foo`? Is there any way to get the caller?

Comment: You have different objects that are calling your -
(void)foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Objective C find caller of method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451342/objective-c-find-caller-of-method). For what do you need it? The (id)sender parameter is passed directly by the method sending the message, there is no magic involved.

Comment: Thank you any way. Because a custom control doesn't pass the self as the sender parameter, so I cannot get some information from the custom control. I will find another way to solve the problem.