# Differents behavior with setter/getter in subclass of UIImageView with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, ios7.1

Since the iOS 7.1 beta 5, I have a strange bug with my little plugin : [link](https://github.com/VivienCormier/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect/)

My plugin is a subclass of `UIImageView`, inside of this class I have an another `UIImageView` called `img`.

I have rewrite the setter and getter of `image` :

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image{

    self.img.image = image;

}

- (UIImage *)image{

    return _img.image;

}
```

So `NSLog(@"%@",self.image)` return `_img.image`, I'm ok.

`NSLog(@"%@",[super image])` return `(null)`, I'm ok.

The problem is with iOS 7.0 `self` don't display an image, but with iOS 7.1 `self` display `_img.image`.

Visually, I don't want a image for `self`, I want the same behavior than iOS 7.0.

So I try a another thing to understand, if I use this setter/getter :

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image{

    [super setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"becomeapanda_tumblr_com_portrait"]];

}

- (UIImage *)image{

    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"becomeapanda_tumblr_com"];

}
```

With iOS 7.0, `self` display this image "becomeapanda_tumblr_com_portrait" but with iOS 7.1 `self` display this image "becomeapanda_tumblr_com".

If I can have any help to understand why with iOS 7.1 my plugin don't have the same behavior, this could be nice!

Comment: Sounds to me like the internal implementation was referencing the image ivar directly in iOS 7.0 and now in iOS7.1 it's using the property getter.

Comment: Yes I'm ok with you, but it's a huge modification. I have read the iOS 7.1 Apple's docs and there is nothing about this.

Comment: Apple doesn't document their internal implementations.

Comment: You'd probably need to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451342/objective-c-find-caller-of-method) to see who's calling the getter and return `nil` if it's `self` calling.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Try it out you forgot [self animaticToScaleAspectFit] to put into your method,

```
    - (void)animateToScaleAspectFitToFrame:(CGRect)frame WithDuration:(float)duration afterDelay:(float)delay{

    if (![self uiimageIsEmpty]) {
        [self initToScaleAspectFitToFrame:frame];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             [self animaticToScaleAspectFit];
                         } completion:nil];
    }else{
        [self animaticToScaleAspectFit];
        NSLog(@"ERROR, UIImageView %@ don't have UIImage",self);
    }  
}
```