# How to find out if background action for a local notification was answered on iPhone or Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchos-3

Is there a way to find out if a local notification with background actions was responded to on the iPhone vs. on the Apple Watch. In both cases they are handled by the iPhone App `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`. Is this information somehwere accesible, maybe in the `UNNotificationResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the UserNotification framework doesn't have such method at the moment.

However, you could check whether the notification handling code is run in your main app or on your Watch Extension and use that information to take appropriate actions.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354990/ios-watchkit-how-to-determine-if-your-code-is-running-in-watch-extension-or-th) question on how to determine where your code is running.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as i understood, the notification handling for **background actions** is always in the iPhone App  `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`. 

So, i guess the link does not really help in my case.